# 301 Redirects in a WordPress site: What will Google Analytics report?

Tags: google, google-analytics, wordpress, 301-redirect

Scenario: user goes to Google and performs a search - one of my old pages shows in the results (a page I have just created a 301 quick redirect for using an app within WordPress) - they click on my result and are redirected to the new page.

Question: will this user show-up in Google Analytics as a direct visitor? If not, how would they show as far as their traffic source?

Answer (score 1):

Server-side 301 redirects should retain the referrer, as captured via the JavaScript `document.referrer`, so the traffic source in this case should be "google.com" (the search engine).

This is covered under the `Redirects and Self-referrals` section [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3198398?hl=en), including an example diagram of a redirect.

For a more detailed discussion on this, with some exceptions to the above (such as right-clicking on the link instead and selecting something like "Open link in new tab"), view the Google Analytics thread [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/analytics/How%2420Google%2420Analytics%2420handles%2420301%2420and%2420302%2420Redirects%2420-%2420THIS%2420IS%2420AN%2420ANSWER/analytics/KQ2RPsLR35Y/yoaXvGpSp04J).